# Is there a way to preserve last day of month while adding interval?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, date-arithmetic

While accounting user we issue bill `31.03`, next bill we will issue at `30.04`, next `31.05` etc.  (for bills issued at start of month: `05.03`, date for next bill will be `05.04`, `05.05` etc)

Doing this at postgresql results at slightly different result:

```sql
tucha=> select '2020-03-31'::timestamptz +interval '1mon';
        ?column?        
------------------------
 2020-04-30 00:00:00+03
(1 row)

tucha=> select '2020-03-31'::timestamptz +interval '1mon' +interval '1mon';
        ?column?        
------------------------
 2020-05-30 00:00:00+03
(1 row)

tucha=> select '2020-03-31'::timestamptz +interval '2mon';
        ?column?        
------------------------
 2020-05-31 00:00:00+03
(1 row)
```

Also you can notice, that depending how you add same interval, you get different results.

Some libraries for date math even provide special parameter. For example excellent **perl** library [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Duration#DateTime::Duration-%3Enew(-...-)) implements `preserve` parameter:

> In `wrap` mode, adding months or years that result in days beyond the end of the new month will roll over into the following month. For instance, adding one year to Feb 29 will result in Mar 1.

> If you specify "end_of_month" mode as `limit`, the end of the month is never crossed. Thus, adding one year to Feb 29, 2000 will result in Feb 28, 2001. If you were to then add three more years this will result in Feb 28, 2004.

> **If you specify "end_of_month" mode as `preserve`**, the same calculation is done as for `limit` except that if the original date is at the end of the month the new date will also be. For instance, adding one month to Feb 29, 2000 will result in Mar 31, 2000.

**NOTICE**: This flag effect only last days of month and leave intact others

Does postgresql have similar flag or probably special date constructor like shown `preserve` option? (probably links to discussions about implementation welcome)

Comment: It is just a matter of precedence and associativity. Add some `()` to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this function can make you happy:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_months_preserve_end(d date, i interval)
   RETURNS date
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
$$SELECT
   CASE WHEN date_trunc('month', d) + INTERVAL '1 month' = d + INTERVAL '1 day'
             AND i = date_trunc('month', i)
        THEN (date_trunc('month', d) + i + INTERVAL '1 month -1 day')::date
        ELSE (d + i)::date
   END$$;
```

It treats days at the end of the month differently.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply truncate the date to the beginning of the month, add two months and substract one day:

```
select date_trunc('month', '2020-03-31'::timestamptz) +interval '2 month -1 day'
```

The upside is that it always return the end of the next month, regardless of the day of the month that you are giving to start with: that is, it will return the same result, for March 7th, 25th or 31th.

What is going on here:

- By truncating date you get first date of month. In our case it is `2020-03-01`.
- Then we add one month to give back truncated month.
- Second added month is our next month. In our case it is `2020-05-01`
- Last we subtract one day, this gives our last day of expected month. In our case it is `2020-04-01`

Comment: Does not work: `select date_trunc('month', '2020-02-01'::timestamptz) +interval '2 month -1 day'`. Here I expect `2020-04-01`. Here I mean that if I issue `01` then next issue date also should be `01` day of next, next monthes. But that effect it return the end of next month always is very interesting. How does it work?

Comment: @EugenKonkov: that requirement did not actually appear in the question...

Comment: I agree with you, but when using mentioned library we can use any day. It will be kept. Please pay attention to: `result in days beyond the end of the new month will roll over into the following month`. So the parameter I am talking about effect only last days, and leave others intact.

Comment: Thanks for notices, I cleanup question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just create some functions:

---

```
DROP function first_day_in_month(deet DATE) ;
CREATE function first_day_in_month(deet DATE) RETURNS date
AS
$func$
        SELECT date_trunc('mon', $1)::date;
$func$
        LANGUAGE sql
        ;


DROP function last_day_in_month(deet DATE) ;
CREATE function last_day_in_month(deet DATE) RETURNS date
AS
$func$
        SELECT (first_day_in_month($1) +interval '1 mon' -interval '1day' )::date;
$func$
        LANGUAGE sql
        ;

SELECT first_day_in_month( CURRENT_DATE );
SELECT last_day_in_month( CURRENT_DATE );
SELECT first_day_in_month( '2020-11-03' );
SELECT last_day_in_month( '2020-11-03' );
```

---

Output:

---

```
DROP FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
DROP FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
 first_day_in_month 
--------------------
 2020-10-01
(1 row)

 last_day_in_month 
-------------------
 2020-10-31
(1 row)

 first_day_in_month 
--------------------
 2020-11-01
(1 row)

 last_day_in_month 
-------------------
 2020-11-30
(1 row)
```